# GIT Branches and Project Settings for Revit Add In

Tags: git

I have a project that I need to maintain various versions of (it is a DLL project and we use multiple versions of Revit). I figured a branch would be the best mechanism but it seems to not allow for different debug settings or reference files.  The source files themselves seem to work, but maybe I have not yet encountered a problem that will exist.  If I have a repository on my local machine, what will allow me to maintain several versions of the reference dlls as well as project settings if branches don't seem to differentiate these things?

Comment: You need to store several versions based on Revit versions?  So you want a set of code to do this for Revit 2016, that for 2017, and so on??  Correct??

Comment: @UchihaItachi Yes that is correct.  For most versions the bulk of the code (views, view models, etc) will remain unchanged.  But the project settings and reference files will be specific to the revit version.  I am now using clones, but this seems to create the problem of having several versions of identical files (like viewmodels that don't change between versions).

Answer (score 0):

So, to ease your woes - you don't need to do any branch work at all!  It's quite simple, actually!  You have different build versions for different versions of Revit.  When you want to apply a certain set of code (as some code is deprecated in newer versions of Revit, or you have to go about getting `Element` properties a different way...), all you have to do is define it.  Since your build versions are defined, you'll use those names.  For instance, for our versions, we define them as `RV2015`, `RV2016`, `RV2017`, and now `RV2018`.  When we need to do a specific block of code for a specific version, it's as easy as:

```
#if RV2015
    //Do this block
#elif RV2016
    //Do this block
#elif RV2017
    //Do this block
#elif RV2018
    //Do this block
#endif
```

No branches needed.  No git needed.  Now, that being said, I still would recommend using git for your source control.  It's insanely useful.  I've seen people lose a months worth of work because they made mistakes in source and didn't know when or where it happened.  Having team members do their work on local branches and then committing them to the master branch allows you to track who is doing what, where and when; and if something breaks, it's as easy as reverting changes to solve the problem.

### HOWEVER

If you specifically want to use branches for different release versions, you can set up your source control through *VisualStudio.com*.

[image]

Once you have created and set up your account, and uploaded your source, you're going to want to create a *Master* branch.  Once all the source is uploaded, you want to then clone the repository to your local disk.  Make this a new file folder - something unique, and aside from the `Documents -> Visual Studio (Year) -> Projects` folder.  This will be what you will work off of now.

This is when you're going to start using VS's git for your source control.  There are 2 tabs in VS when you start it: *Solution Explorer* and *Team Explorer* - you want the latter for source control (look at picture above).  You'll see a little green plug icon next to the house - this is how you connect to your remote branches for synching.

### NEXT - CREATING YOUR BRANCHES

[image]

This is the easy part.  From the *Team Explorer* home (house icon), you want to click on *Branches*.  When you're there, it looks like this:

[image]

Right-click on your *Master* branch and select *Create New Branch*.  You should get this screen:

[image]

Give your branch a name like `RV2016`, `RV2017` and so on...  Once you have those branches, just replace the code that's in there (it copies from *Master* or whatever branch you create it from) with that of the version you want.

### ONCE YOU HAVE ALL YOUR BRANCHES:

All you have to do to store them to the online repo is Right-Click the branch and select *Publish*.  That sends it to the online repo.  If you make changes to the branch, you can go to the *Sync* tab and *Push* your changes for the branch.  *Note:  The branch must be checked out for this.

That's about it.  If I think of anything else or I need to add to this, just check for updates.

Comment: Thanks for the insight . . . I think this is a creative solution for code bits, but still I don't think solves what I'm really looking for: that the debugger settings have to change for the target executable every time I switch versions (likewise the reference dlls for RevitAPIUI and RevitAPI should be the corresponding version of Revit).  I agree about the usefullness of Git . . . its an upgrade from the thumb drive for me when wanting to get some stuff done at home instead of in the office.

Comment: I have found this method to be the most efficient.  If you have your heart set on creating separate branches for everything, then I can show you that too.  Couple of questions.  What IDE are you using?  What language are you coding in?  What are you currently using for source control?

Comment: I use Visual Studio 2015 Community, C# and am using git for source control.

Comment: Check my edited answer.  Please don't forget to mark this as an answer and upvote if this works for you.  Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Well thanks for that, but all of that is what I've been doing for a few years.  The specifics of my question have yet to be addressed in your answer.  I certainly appreciate your time, but I am comfortable with how to use git for the actual code files.  The project settings are what I repeatedly am pointing to, specifically the debug target executable and the specific versions of the reference files (RevitAPI and RevitAPIUI) are what seem to not be able to be differentiated in the git branching model.

Comment: Well you could always just add ALL the resources to one branch, and use the `if` statements, so when you switch between debug versions, it knows what resources to use.  That's what we do.  We have a rather large Add-In for Revit and it works great.  Other than that, I don't know how to help you.